# Voltage divider ambiguity

Tags: analysis, voltage-divider, theory

considering the following circuit :

```
         R1
    |--/\/\/\--------- A
    |                |
    |+               |
   (E1)              |
    |                |
    |------/\/\/\----|
    |        R2
    |
    |------/\/\/\---- B
              R3
```

Can anyone please explain to me why the voltage V(AB) calculated by the 
voltage divider rule is equal to

Vab=[R2/(R1+R2)]*E1 ?

Is it fair to assert that you consider only R1 and R2 because R3 has no current flowing in it therefore has null voltage ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, potential difference is a function of the current flowing and the resistance it is flowing across.

> V = I * R

[image: Voltage Divider, Fritzing schematic]

Thus, since point B is a hypothetical open circuit, current through R3 is zero, hence voltage across R3 is also zero.

*As an aside, while the ascii-art schematic is better than none, there are a number of simple, and free, schematic drawing tools out there, such as [Fritzing](http://fritzing.org/), for making a schematic that provides greater clarity to the reader of your question.*

Answer (score 1):

So if you took a voltmeter and measured the voltage between the positive terminal of E1 and "B", you would get V(E1).  This is because a resistor resists the flow of current, but it doesn't **prevent** that flow indefinitely.

Let's add an extra label to your schematic:

```
         R1
    |--/\/\/\--------- A
    |                |
    |+               |
   (E1)              |
    |                |
  C |------/\/\/\----|
    |        R2
    |
    |------/\/\/\---- B
              R3
```

So let's now pretend that V(BC) is initially... say... 16,000V (static charge).  Since V=IR, we get some massive current flowing through R3, right? And you will!  But the number of electrons which needed to flow to fix that potential difference only needs to fill up the metal lead on the other side of the resistor, which only takes a few nanoseconds (give or take, there's a lot of weird assumptions in my example).  So that potential quickly decreases as electrons flow to the B terminal, and thus the current through R3 decreases, until there is no potential difference across R3.  No potential means that C and B are equal, and so R3 doesn't really matter anymore.

Now that being said, even if R3 had been connected such that B was at the E1+ it *still* wouldn't have changed the value of the voltage divider rule because (assuming that E1 is a **voltage** source) the amount of current flowing out of E1 would increase, but the voltage across R1 and R2 would still have been the same.

Just to be thorough, I'll derive where the voltage divider equation came from, so that you can see why R3 should have no effect.

Since
$$
V_{source}=I*R
$$
We know that
$$
I= { V_{source} \over R }
$$
$$
I_{R_1 R_2}= { V_{source} \over R_1 + R_2 }
$$
Since the current will be the same through both R1 and R2, to get V(R2) we just say:
$$
V_{R_2} = R_2*I_{R_2}
$$
Substituting I(total) for I(R2)
$$
V_{R_2} = R_2*({ V_{source} \over R_1 + R_2 })
$$
Which we change around a bit to get:
$$
V_{R_2} = V_{source}*({ R_2 \over R_1 + R_2 })
$$

So as long as the voltage across E1 is constant, R3 won't have much effect.  If R3 was connected in such a way that it altered the amount of current flowing through R1 and R2, then it would change things!